# magento Every Product detail page showing 404

Tags: magento

I have shifted from live site to local site, the product detail page is showing a 404 page. I tired re-index multiple time.clear cache. check database also but it still displays a 404 page.

[image]

Comment: check core_config_data table and URL in that table

Comment: How does your URL look? Can you give us an example.

Answer (score 0):

There can be several things you can check:-
1. Check for url in core_config_data and also check cookie url.
2. Check on server for mod_rewrite module may be this is not enabled on local, this can also be the reason if you were using SEO friendly url.

Clear the cache once you are done with these. It will be great if you can tell how url for PDP page is been generated on local.

Answer (score 0):

my url is like this

http://localhost/reyassoc/10x-a4-silver-diamond-brochure-island-stand.html

same it working on existing live site

Answer (score 0):

Run below sql query

```
SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE path = "web/seo/use_rewrites";
```

See whether the value 1 or not, if the value is 1, try to change it to 0.
This value is for SEO friendly url, which removes index.php from your store url.

Also, you can replace your .htaccess file with default one in Magento root folder.
Your server may have problem with mod_rewrite module or its configuration, you may re-install it.